# How to merge dating correctly

Tags: r, dataset, combinations, aggregation

I'm trying to merge 7 complete data frames into one great wide data frame. I figured I have to do this stepwise and merge 2 frames into 1 and then that frame into another so forth until all 7 original frames becomes one.

```
fil2005: "ID" "abr_2005" "lop_2005" "ins_2005"
fil2006: "ID" "abr_2006" "lop_2006" "ins_2006"
```

But the variables "abr_2006" "lop_2006" "ins_2006" and 2005 are all either 0,1.

Now the things is, I want to either merge or do a dcast of some sort (I think) to make these two long data frames into one wide data frame were both "abr_2005" "lop_2005" "ins_2005" and abr_2006" "lop_2006" "ins_2006" are in that final file.

When I try

```
$fil_2006.1  <- merge(x=fil_2005, y=fil_2006, by="ID__", all.y=T)
```

all the variables with _2005 at the end if it is saved to the fil_2006.1, but the variables ending in _2006 doesn't.

I'm apparently doing something wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you put those underscores after `ID__`? Otherwise, the code you provided will work

An example:

```
dat1 <- data.frame("ID"=seq(1,20,by=2),"varx2005"=1:10, "vary2005"=2:11)
dat2 <- data.frame("ID"=5:14,"varx2006"=1:20, "vary2006"=21:40)
# create data frames of differing lengths 

head(dat1)
   ID varx2005 vary2005
1  1        1        2
2  3        2        3
3  5        3        4
4  7        4        5
5  9        5        6  
6 11        6        7

head(dat2)
   ID varx2006 vary2006
1  5        1       21
2  6        2       22
3  7        3       23
4  8        4       24
5  9        5       25
6 10        6       26

merged <- merge(dat1,dat2,by="ID",all=T)
head(merged)

   ID varx2006 vary2006 varx2005 vary2005
1  1       NA       NA        1        2
2  3       NA       NA        2        3
3  5        1       21        3        4
4  5       11       31        3        4
5  7       13       33        4        5
6  7        3       23        4        5
```

Comment: Yes the reason for __ is that i want to keep every ID that contains __ at the end. The new ID is "ID__". The file is quite large and have alot of ID therefore i simply wanted to keep thoose that contained "ID__" in the final merged file. Also i have alot of variable names. The only differences in variables name from both files is the year (either 2005 or 2006). Now when i try my code every ID is in the merged dataframe but somehow the variables from 2006 gets NA all of them. Appreciate that you took ur time to answear!

Comment: Strange, think i actually solved it by simply removing all.x=T. Can't understand why it works though.